# Get a number like string, convert it and add one every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had this question on an interview and I failed. I was close with my answer but I didn't finish the script.
The question was: get the text from the paragraph, add one and put back into paragraph  every second the new value.
My logic was that in the p the number is a string. I convert it in number with parseInt, then check if is notNaN, alert not a number, else increase the value with one and put it back into the p.

Anyone please tell me where I was wrong.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval("addOne()", 1000);
});

function addOne() {
    var divP = $("div p").text();
    parseInt(divP);
    if (isNaN(divP)) {
        alert("Not a number!");
    } else {
        divP++;
        $("div p").text();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: last one should be `$("div p").text(divP);`

Comment: Hint: What does parseInt() return?

Comment: 1) You don't assign the result of `parseInt()` to anything. 2) you aren't providing the `radix` parameter 3) you should provide the reference of the `addOne()` function to `setInterval()` to avoid the intrinsic use of `eval()`. 4) you're using the getter of `text()`, not setting the value of `divP`

Comment: Wow, I was so close. Too bad that they didn't tell me that I'm very close. Thank you Gene

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have quite a few issues:

- You don't assign the result of `parseInt()` to anything
- You aren't providing the `radix` parameter to `parseInt()`
- You should provide the reference of the `addOne()` function to `setInterval()` to avoid the intrinsic use of `eval()`
- You're using the getter of `text()`, not setting the value of `divP`

Here's a working example:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(addOne, 1000);
});

function addOne() {
    var divP = parseInt($("div p").text(), 10);
    if (isNaN(divP)) {
        alert("Not a number!");
    } else {
        $("div p").text(++divP);
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ze6fLL0m/)

It could also be argued that calling an `alert()` to show UI state information (especially in a function called every second) is not good practice.

Comment: Can i ask something setInterval("addOne()", 1000); will this call the function `addOne()` even if it is inside `""`?

Comment: It will but it uses `eval()` internally, hence why it's considered bad practice. Always pass the function reference directly, where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
    $("div p").html();
```

instead of

```
    $("div p").text();
```

Sorry,
it must be html instead of val because val is for input elements.
Thank You

Comment: p has `no value` i dont know who upvote but i think `.html()` could have been correct

Comment: Who upvoted this?? Firstly, what improvement would be made by replacing one unasssigned getter with another? Also `p` elements *have no value to retrieve*

Comment: Again, even with the update you're calling a getter method without assigning the result *to* anything, when the OP actually wants to *set* a value...

Comment: First he want to get value and add 1 in that value as well and then assign this value

Comment: Exactly, your answer solves neither of those requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 errors I can find.

1. You didn't assign the `parseInt(divP)` to anything.

   **Should be:** 
     `divP = parseInt(divP);`
2. You are not using the `setInterval` properly.

   **Should be:** `setInterval(function(){ addOne(); }, 1000);`
3. You didn't put the new value to the element `$("div p").text();`.

   **Should be:** `$("div p").text(divP);`

Do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){ addOne(); }, 1000);
});

function addOne() {
    var divP = $("div p").text();
    divP = parseInt(divP);
    if (isNaN(divP)) {
        alert("Not a number!");
    } else {
        divP++;
        $("div p").text(divP);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snvq9ume/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here.
  HTML

```
 <div>
 <button id="btnClickStart" >
 Start Increment
 </button>
 <button id="btnClickStop">
 Stop Increment
 </button>
 <p id="pId">
 I am testing this script if it will work the 1st time.
 </p>

</div>


JAVASCRIPT

$('#btnClickStart').click(function() {
startIncrement();
});
$('#btnClickStop').click(function() {
stopIncrement();
});
var myInterval ;
function startIncrement(){
myInterval = setInterval(function(){ addOne(); }, 1000);
}

function stopIncrement() {
clearInterval(myInterval);
}

var _array = [];
function addOne() {
var divP = document.getElementById('pId').innerHTML;
var _array = [];
for (var i = 0, len = divP.length; i < len; i++) {
    parseInt(divP[i]);
  if (isNaN(divP[i])) {
    //alert("Not a number!");
       } else{
            _array.push(divP[i]);
    }
 }

  for (var j = 0, len = _array.length; j < len; j++) {
    _str =parseInt( _array[j]);
    if(!isNaN(_str) ){
      divPLast= divP.replace(_str, parseInt(_str)+1);
     }
   }
    document.getElementById('pId').innerHTML = divPLast; 
 }
```